# Python application for updating an embedded device - is it feasible?

Tags: python, windows-ce

I am considering to write a tool for updating a WinCE based device. The update procedure consists of following steps:

1. get several files from two different zip-archives
2. start target and while it is booting send a command over serial interface RS232 (switch in bootstrap mode)
3. transfer WinCE-OS image and a flash-tool over FTP
4. connect via telnet and execute the flash-tool
5. reboot target
6. transfer customization files via FTP

Currently all this is done manually, which is very error prone and time consuming. Especially the step 6 is a pain in the a**, because FTP server on WinCE target often breaks.

I hope, Python could help me accomplish all these steps, the first look in the libraries showed, that there is everithing there: ziplib, ftplib, seriallib, telnetlib.

Does anyone have done something similar? What are hidden problems there?

Thank you for any hint!

EDIT:
There is not Python on target (and ihmo there is no need for). 
Target provides telnetd, ftpd via ethernet connection and a boot-console via serial connection. The entire file system is exposed via telnet and ftp - so any file can be accessed through these protocols from the host.

Comment: Do you mean running Python apps on the host, target, or both?

Comment: @mtrw: Thank you very much for the question, It is very important and I've missed to mention: There is not Python on target. Target provides telnetd, ftpd via ethernet connection and a boot-console via serial connection. Ihmo, there is no need to execute Python on the target as the entire file system is exposed via telnet and ftp - so any file can be accessed through these protocols from the host.

Comment: Please **update** your question to be complete.  Don't add comments.  Fix the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) or [python for windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to send the serial command, [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) to send telnet commands and and [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html) for the FTP part. Eventually, you even can [install Python on the WinCE device](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonce/), but should should not need it.